# how to use activity class in fragment class

Tags: android

need a bit of help,i have a login page from there a intent is passed to next after validation ,the next page is a predefined layout(swipeable tabs)now i know how to create different layouts on different swipes and there will be different java file for each of the swipe,the java file is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.Global;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
/**
 * @author sanketh
 *
 */

public class profile extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

       prof p1=new prof();
      p1.setname(Gloabal.getemail());
       return rootView;


   }
}
```

this code works fine without any problem ,but now i want to  use layout objects like textview,edittext to set text from here and i can't do it because my class is not extending activity class so  i created  a class which extends activity in the same  file but it how can i make tht class also run also with above provided class

```
class prof extends Activity
   {
       TextView t1;
       datab dat;
       @Override

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.profile);
             t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget35);  
       }
       prof()
       {
           //setname(Gloabal.getemail());
       }
       public void setname(String e)
       {
           Toast.makeText(Gloabal.getcontext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           t1.setText("sanketh");
            /*Cursor cur=dat.getname(e);
            cur.moveToFirst();
*/      
       }
       /*@Override
       public void onStart()
       {
           super.onStart();
           dat=new datab(this);
           setname(Gloabal.getemail());
       }*/

   }
```

this extra added class to it so I cant display some contents onto the page

Comment: You can access the activity from a fragment using this.getActivity()

Comment: that just answered my many questions,thanx a ton mate

Comment: Let me put that in an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can access the activity from a fragment using [this.getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
   TextView t1;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false); 

       t1=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.widget35);  
       t1.setText("sanketh "+Gloabal.getemail());
       return rootView;


   }
```

Comment: ok u solved my one of the prob,same way i want to instantiate object another class named "data" eg data dat; and inside oncreateview(){  dat=new datab(this);},but it doesnot allow to use this variable,any solution for tht?

Comment: @user3203211 you can create object as it is. but you cannot access textview of other activity.

Comment: @user3203211 you want to access a textview in activity and the fragment is associated with the same activtiy. you can use `TextView tv= (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1)`

Answer (score 0):

Owerride onAttach() method in your Fragment and save Activity to any variable.
For Example:

```
public class profile extends Fragment {
   private Activity myActivity = null;

   @Override
   public void onAttach (Activity activity){
       this.myActivity = activity;
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

       prof p1=new prof();
      p1.setname(Gloabal.getemail());
       return rootView;


   }
}
```

After that you can use this Activity.
For example

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(myActivity)
```